# Using singularitygs: horizontal scroll when resizing

Tags: responsive-design, singularitygs

I'm having a strange problem in a project where I'm using the singularitygs for the first time: when resizing the viewport I get an **horizontal scrollbar** *bellow* the 838+/- px... and I'm having a really hard time figuring it out the reason and if it's related with singularity.

The project development website is available at:

http://goo.gl/kBkKm

I would really appreciate a hand from anyone more experienced.
Thanks for your time.

Best,
B

Answer (score 2):

This isn’t a singularity issue but something is overflowing your `<section>` tags. Just style your `<section>` tags with `overflow:hidden`. Looks like you are applying your styles to `#about, #process, #services, #clients, #contacts` so just adding `overflow:hidden` there works just fine.

Also, Nice to see you using Omnes ;)

Comment: Hi Scott,

You are (almost) always my savior, but this time it was the lack of `margin: 0` in the `nav ul`. It was driving me crazy and being a newbie to singularitygs made me think I was doing something wrong.

Thanks, again. :)
Btw, Omnes is my company official typeface. We think is really nice and underrated.

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro Please accept the answer by clicking the «V» icon next to it.